# Return the column name(s) for a specific value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

where I have found this option in other languages such as R or SQL but I am not quite sure how to go about this in Pandas.

So I have a file with 1262 columns and 1 row and need the column headers to return for every time that a specific value appears.

Say for example this test dataframe:

```
Date               col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7 
01/01/2016 00:00   37.04   36.57   35.77   37.56   36.79   35.90   38.15
```

And I need to locate the column name for e.g. where value = 38.15. What is the best way of doing so?

Thanks

Comment: This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/42639207 , the general case "get names for columns specifying criteria".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seeing as you only have a single row then you can call `iloc[0]` on the result and use this to mask the columns:

```
In [47]:
df.columns[(df == 38.15).iloc[0]]

Out[47]:
Index(['col7'], dtype='object')
```

Breaking down the above:

```
In [48]:
df == 38.15

Out[48]:
             Date   col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6  col7
01/01/2016  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  True

In [49]:
(df == 38.15).iloc[0]

Out[49]:
Date    False
col1    False
col2    False
col3    False
col4    False
col5    False
col6    False
col7     True
Name: 01/01/2016, dtype: bool
```

You can also use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas.DataFrame.idxmax) with param `axis=1`:

```
In [52]:
(df == 38.15).idxmax(axis=1)[0]

Out[52]:
'col7'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried all three and they work. I prefer the third solution, namely `(df == 38.15).idxmax(axis=1)[0]` because it gives the value of the column right away

Comment: I agree, it's not immediately obvious that you can use `idxmax` like this as the name suggests index but the `axis` param is designed specifically for finding the max value column-wise

Comment: Hi! is there a fast way to do this (df.columns[(df == 38.15).iloc[0]]
)  for every row? I mean, for every row, I want to get the name of the column that contains certain value. I've tried doing a for cicle, but I have 11MM of rows... so although it works, its taking a lot of time. Thanks!

Comment: If I have to check for multiple numbers. e.g. 38.15 and 37.56 and print particular columns?

Comment: And how to do it for every row?   How to create a column with a string, that names all the columns in this row with value 38.15???
df['correct_columns'] = ', '.join(df.columns[df==38.15])  - does not work for every row. Says "too many indeces", i suppose it does not check the row, but the whole dataframe instead.

Comment: strange, it doesn't work for me. I have a df with multiple rows, multiple columns and the entries and strings and dates, not floats. And the suggested approach doesn't return the desired columns

Comment: Instead this works `df.columns[df.isin(['SOME_STRING']).any()] `. why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use data frame slicing and then get the columns names:

```
df.ix[:,df.loc[0] == 38.15].columns
```

output:

```
Index([u'col7'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks it would be nice if I indeed wanted the index and fast but in this case column name is what suits my problem best.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have this [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtcyl.png) . Checking only the first three rows of the [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtcyl.png) we want to get the name of the column where the specific value is 5.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    df.head(3)
```

We can do this:

```
In[61]:
for index, row in df[:3].iterrows():
    for i in range(len(df.columns)): 
        if row[i] == 5:
            print(row.index[i])
Out[61]:
'D'
```

Answer (score 0):

just for the sake of throwing something a bit different into the ring:

```
row = df.iloc[0]
row.reset_index().set_index(0).loc[38.15]
```