# Pandas: Return column headers for columns satisfying certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data and want to get the column headers for columns with a small sample size (eg < 90% total rows). How do I get a list of them, perhaps returned as either a list or a dataframe?

In the example below, I will like to get `FieldC` as output.

Using `train_df.head()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2000 entries, 0 to 1999
Data columns (total 100 columns):
Id               2000 non-null int64
FieldA           2000 non-null int64
FieldB           2000 non-null object
FieldC           1675 non-null float64
FieldD           2000 non-null int64
FieldE           2000 non-null object
...more fields...
```

Using `train_df.count()<2000*0.9`:

```
Id               False
FieldA           False
FieldB           False
FieldC           True
FieldD           False
FieldE           False
...more fields...
```

Comment: Looks like you want row headers, not column headers? `train_df[train_df.count()<2000*0.9].index`

Comment: @DYZ thank you for your comment. I have tried that as well, but I got the error `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`

Comment: Sorry. Must be `train_df.count()[train_df.count()<2000*0.9].index`. Or, rather, more efficiently, `count=train_df.count(); count[count<2000*0.9].index`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> _=pandas.DataFrame({'horse':[3,None],'cow':[1,2],'sheep':[None,None]})
>>> _
   cow  horse sheep
0    1    3.0  None
1    2    NaN  None
>>> criterion2=_.columns[_.count()>2]
>>> criterion1=_.columns[_.count()>1]
>>> criterion0=_.columns[_.count()>0]
>>> criterion2
Index([], dtype='object')
>>> criterion1
Index(['cow'], dtype='object')
>>> criterion0
Index(['cow', 'horse'], dtype='object')
>>> _[criterion2]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1]
>>> _[criterion1]
   cow
0    1
1    2
>>> _[criterion0]
   cow  horse
0    1    3.0
1    2    NaN
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.22.0'
```

This pandas.Index of 'object' can also be converted to a sequence of text strings.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do :

```
columnsToBeReturn=[]
max=df.shape[0] #getting the shape of the entire dataframe so the biggest number of rows
for col in df.columns: 
   if len(df[col])<max*0.9:
       columsToBeReturn.append(col)
return columnsToBeReturn
```