# Select column index in pandas dataframe based on values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file like so:

```
Id               col1    col2    col3     
a                 7.04   0.3     1.2    
b                 0.3    1.7     .1   
c                 0.34   0.05    1.3   
d                 0.4    1.60    3.1
```

I want to convert it to a data frame thresholding on 0.5 . If the values is greater than or equal to 0.5 then the column is counted , otherwise it is not counted.

```
Id               classes    
a                 col1,col3    
b                 col2        
c                 col3   
d                 col2,col3
```

The closest solution I found is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331568/return-the-column-names-for-a-specific-value-in-a-pandas-dataframe). However it deals with single rows, not multiple rows. For multiple rows, the best I have is iterate through all the rows. I need a succinct expression without for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first and then [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for extract columns by condition. Last remove empty strings by `list comprehension`:

```
df = df.set_index('Id')
s = np.where(df > .5, ['{}, '.format(x) for x in df.columns], '')
df['new'] = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], index=df.index)
print (df)
    col1  col2  col3         new
Id                              
a   7.04  0.30   1.2  col1, col3
b   0.30  1.70   0.1        col2
c   0.34  0.05   1.3        col3
d   0.40  1.60   3.1  col2, col3
```

Similar for new `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'classes': [''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], 
                    'Id': df.index})
print (df1)
  Id     classes
0  a  col1, col3
1  b        col2
2  c        col3
3  d  col2, col3
```

And if necessary remove empty with `,`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'classes': [''.join(x).strip(', ').replace(', ',',') for x in s], 
                    'Id': df.index})
print (df1)

  Id    classes
0  a  col1,col3
1  b       col2
2  c       col3
3  d  col2,col3
```

Detail:

```
print (s)
[['col1, ' '' 'col3, ']
 ['' 'col2, ' '']
 ['' '' 'col3, ']
 ['' 'col2, ' 'col3, ']]
```

Alternative with `apply` (slowier):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Id')
         .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.index[x > .5]), 1)
         .reset_index(name='classes'))
print (df1)
  Id    classes
0  a  col1,col3
1  b       col2
2  c       col3
3  d  col2,col3
```

Answer (score 2):

Comprehension after clever multiplication... This assumes that `Id` is the index.

```
df.assign(classes=[
    ','.join(s for s in row if s)
    for row in df.ge(.5).mul(df.columns).values
])

    col1  col2  col3    classes
Id                             
a   7.04  0.30   1.2  col1,col3
b   0.30  1.70   0.1       col2
c   0.34  0.05   1.3       col3
d   0.40  1.60   3.1  col2,col3
```

---

**Setup Fun Trick**
Custom subclass of `str` that redefines string addition to include a `','`

```
class s(str):
    def __add__(self, other):
        if self and other:
            return s(super().__add__(',' + other))
        else:
            return s(super().__add__(other))
```

**Fun Trick**

```
df.ge(.5).mul(df.columns).applymap(s).sum(1)

Id
a    col1,col3
b         col2
c         col3
d    col2,col3
dtype: object
```