# Return Column name for specified value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My question is extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331568/return-the-column-names-for-a-specific-value-in-a-pandas-dataframe). Although the question asked are same, answers are only applicable to very specific situation.

Assuming same data set, I want to add column with column name containing specific value

```
Date               col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7 
01/01/2016 00:00   37.04   36.57   35.77   37.56   36.79   35.90   38.15
```

However, I have large number of rows, and the value I want to find is neither max nor min (say i want to col name with value 36.79).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare all values of `DataFrame` and test at least one `True` by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) - then mask is used for filter columns names:

```
c = df.columns[(df == 36.79).any()].tolist()
```

But because working with floats and possible [some accuracy problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) is better use [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with select only numeric columns:

```
#if possible some non numeric columns
df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
c = df1.columns[np.any(np.isclose(df1, 36.79), axis=0)].tolist()

#if all columns are numeric
c = df.columns[np.any(np.isclose(df, 36.79), axis=0)].tolist()
```

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
               Date   col1   col2   col3   col4   col5  col6   col7
0  01/01/2016 00:00  37.04  36.57  35.77  37.56  36.79  35.9  38.15
1  01/02/2016 00:00  37.04  36.57  35.77  37.56  36.79  35.9  36.79 <-last value changed

df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
c = df1.columns[np.any(np.isclose(df1, 36.79), axis=0)].tolist()
print (c)
['col5', 'col7']
```

Last if want first matched value if exist is possible use `next` with `iter` for possible pass default value if empty list (no value match):

```
print (next(iter(c), 'no match'))
col5
```

---

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
c = df1.columns[np.any(np.isclose(df1, 100), axis=0)].tolist()
print (c)
[]

print (next(iter(c), 'no match'))
no match
```