# Python Pandas : Return column header/name where values equal the other in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the column header location(s) where the value in the last column equals a value in any of the other columns. This should be appended as a new column. Assuming I have the dataframe:

```
       category    color          size    max_value      
a      [2, 1]     [1,1,1]      [1,1,1]      [1,1,1]    
b       [2,1]   [1,1,1,1]    [1,1,1,1]        [2,1]            
c         [1]         [3]      [1,1,1]          [3]
```

While this has been answered in some form here: [Return the column name(s) for a specific value in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331568/return-the-column-names-for-a-specific-value-in-a-pandas-dataframe), I have **lists** as opposed to numbers in my case and keeps throwing an error

I would expect the results to be:

```
    category         color     size       max_value       matchedcols
a      [2, 1]     [1,1,1]      [1,1,1]      [1,1,1]       color,size
b       [2,1]   [1,1,1,1]    [1,1,1,1]        [2,1]         category
c         [1]         [3]     [1,1,1]           [3]            color
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the comparison after dropping down to `numpy`

```
m = df.iloc[:, :-1].to_numpy() == df.max_value.to_numpy()[:, None]
#array([[False,  True,  True],
#       [ True, False, False],
#       [False,  True, False]])

df['matched_cols'] = [', '.join(df.columns[:-1][x]) for x in m]
#  category         color          size  max_value matched_cols
#0   [2, 1]     [1, 1, 1]     [1, 1, 1]  [1, 1, 1]  color, size
#1   [2, 1]  [1, 1, 1, 1]  [1, 1, 1, 1]     [2, 1]     category
#2      [1]           [3]     [1, 1, 1]        [3]        color
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like a problem for `pandas` library, but anyway.

```
df = df.applymap(tuple)
cols = df.drop('max_value', 1).columns
```

```
df['matchedcols'] = (df.drop('max_value', 1)
                       .eq(df['max_value'], axis=0)
                       .apply(lambda s: ', '.join(cols[s]), 1))
```

---

```
  category         color          size  max_value  matchedcols
a   (2, 1)     (1, 1, 1)     (1, 1, 1)  (1, 1, 1)  color, size
b   (2, 1)  (1, 1, 1, 1)  (1, 1, 1, 1)     (2, 1)     category
c     (1,)          (3,)     (1, 1, 1)       (3,)        color
```

Of course if you need the lists, just do all operations in a copied `df`, keep the original and just add back at the `df['matchedcols'] = (...)` part.

Answer (score 0):

As you said last column, so I use `iloc` and `dot` here

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,:-1].eq(df.iloc[:,-1], axis=0)
df['matchedcols'] = df1.dot(df1.columns+',').str.strip(',')

Out[971]:
  category         color          size  max_value matchedcols
a  [2, 1]   [1, 1, 1]     [1, 1, 1]     [1, 1, 1]  color,size
b  [2, 1]   [1, 1, 1, 1]  [1, 1, 1, 1]  [2, 1]     category
c  [1]      [3]           [1, 1, 1]     [3]        color
```