# How can I access a column cell by position?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a data frame and I would like to access to one of my columns but only the cell of my data frame by position.

I mean, this is my df:

```
| A   |  B  |  C
------|-----|--
|  1  |  2  | 3
|  4  |  5  | 5
|
```

I want to access to the cell [0, 1] I mean "B" these are the line codes that I used

```
df.iloc[0,1]
```

But my result was **2** and I want the letter B in my result.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm confused, do you want just the column name "B"? Or B and 2.

Comment: Just the column name "B", cell [0,1]. But iloc only works to access to the position of the starting of the data frame, exlcudes the column position so If I said df.iloc[0,1] my result is 2 not B

Comment: [Return the column name(s) for a specific value in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331568)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column names are not part of the DataFrame that can be accessed by iloc.
To access the column labels use `df.columns`. So a solution might be:

```py
df.columns[1] #gives you B
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([df.columns.to_list()], columns=df.columns.to_list()), df])
df.iloc[0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the names of the columns as

```
df.columns
```

now it returns the name of columns with dtype object
this can get you the value b
df.columns[1]

Comment: df.cloumns[1]--this gives you the value b